# how to update a value in jsp after a button action to display the new value

Tags: jsp, jsf-2

I use an `outputText` to display a value of a calculation. I added a `commandButton` to reset the value.

```
 <h:outputText id="lost" value="#{calculation.lost}" ></h:outputText>
 <h:commandButton id="resetLost" value="Reset" action="#{calculation.setLost(0.0)}"></h:commandButton>
```

The `setLost` method just executes a code insertion like this: `lost=lost`.

I assumed that the `outputText` would be updated automatically but the value doesn't change. I tried also to refresh the page automatically without effect. Also I tried to use javascript.

Is it possible that the `commandButton` action to not be executed? And why? What is wrong in this piece of code?

Comment: what about your bean ?please be more specific

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your action to see if it gets called.

Comment: @mstzn What about the bean? it gets the variable "lost" and defined setter/getter as well.

Comment: I mean you should show your calculation class.and please do what @f_puras said

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked Perhaps you just didn't have a form at all or a conversion/validation error has occurred? Anyway, just doing some basic HTTP and Java debugging so that you can track what got executed or not should already give a lot of insight.

Comment: Less likely but maybe the reason of not working could be `lost = lost` in setter method, correct it as `this.lost = lost` :).

Comment: Sorry but i didnt managed to debug the application appropriately. I used Netbean for this purpose and I couldnt find the variables. I am not used to debug web apps. I dont know how to continue.